# Refresh Div and Animate the change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, refresh

I know how to refresh the contents of a `DIV`, however instead of it just appearing I want to `animate` that change. The `div` is essentially a collection of boxes and when a user accepts an offer it needs to `'move'` into that `div`.

How would I approach this using `Javascript/Jquery`?
Thanks.

Comment: Good for you that you know, how about you enlighten us about it so that we are able to build on your pattern and help you.

Comment: what have you tried/what do you have in mind - do you have any code to show?

Comment: Essentially the div contents is an include and you reload it.... My initial idea was to essentially spoof the new one using append(); using JS to insert the new div in there however it wasn't feasible as there was a lot of database driven content within that of which I couldn't realistically assign to JS vars aswell as PHP ones.

Comment: OK, it seems that you should read that first http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I'm just looking for a push in the right direction - not a specific answer, IE code to do it. I can't think of another way of approaching this problem without endless amounts of repeatative database queries

Comment: AJAX or if you target the very end of browsers version - HTML 5 websockets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a `<div/>` which is a container of users accepted offers

```
<div id="offersContainer">
    <div class="offer">
        Offer 1
    </div>
    <div class="offer">
        Offer 2
    </div>
</div>
```

To add a new element inside offers div, you use the `.append()` method.

```
$("#offersContainer").append("<div id='offer_5'>New Offer</div>");
```

Then, you can animate the new offer

```
$("#offer_5").animate({ "background-color": "blue" }, 1000);
```

Is this what you are trying to do?

**Edit**

jquery AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Offers/GetOffer",
    data: { offer_Id: 5 },
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
        // data can be html or json, depends on what you return from you're action
        // console.log(data);

        $("#offersContainer").append(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes - exactly, the only problem with it is that the contents on the offer is largely database driven, of which most of the data is stored as PHP vars. To get them into JS it would require a lot of re-querying. Unless there's a way round that one too?

Comment: AJAX or if you target the very end of browsers version - HTML 5 websockets

Comment: You should have a method that returns just an offer from database, and return it with jquery AJAX. [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Guess thats the only way round that one - cheers for the answers guys.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by **move into that div**

You can wrap divs new content in another html element and show it with some animation.

```
<div></div>
newContent = '<span id="whatever" display="none">newContent</span>';
```

When you have this structure in DOM

```
<div>
   <span id="old">oldContent</span>
   <span id="whatever" display="none">newContent</span>
</div>
```

and

```
$('#old').animateOUT(callback(){
   $('#whatever').animateIN();
   $(this).remove();
})
```

`animateOUT,animateIN,callback`

aren't real functions but animation effects of your choice: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Comment: There is basically two columns on my page - New Offers and Replied Offers. When a user, for instance presses the "Accept" button on the offer it needs to be placed in the next column. The replied offers is an include, could I use that include to essentially shrink it to 0, load the new content then increase the height accordingly?

Comment: That is possible but this is more of a specific problem , you can ask about it too, by providing details. I've tried to give you a concept, here.

Comment: Thats all I was after - just a means of solving my problem, I'll do the leg work. I know its a bit on the vague side.

Answer (score 0):

You will either have to add a new element inside your main div that you want to expand and animate it in or just replace the main div with a new div and call `slideDown()` (or whatever other animation you want to do) on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for your work

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('div_id').innerHTML=location.reload(); //Reload code
</script>
```